# Arrays getting passed through a function

Tags: c

I am learning how variables are passed to functions by value, while arrays are passed by reference.

I ran my script to verify that, however the pointer addresses are different. Why is that?

```
void arrayFunction(int array[4]);

int main(void){
    int foo[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    printf("This is the address to foo in main: %p\n",&foo);
    arrayFunction(foo);
}

void arrayFunction(int array[4]){
    printf("This is the address to array in method: %p\n", &array);
    array[0] = 22;
}
```

Comment: One can pass the address of "built-in" datatype variables to a function. (eg `char`, `int`, `double`.) Complex datatypes like arrays and `struct`'s are passed as the address of the first element of the datatype.

Comment: "Arrays are passed by reference" is a simplified statement  what happens is that an array *decays* to a pointer of its first element, and that pointer gets passed by value (like any other pointer or anything else). The address of the pointer will not be preserved and is irrelevant. What happens next is `int array[4]` in the parameter list of your function does not declare an array, it declares a pointer. This is called "type adjustment". The declaration is equivalent to `int* array`.

Answer (score 0):

`&array` is the address of the array variable in the stack of the called function. However that's implemented as a pointer that points to the same array elements.

Here is a modified version of your program showing that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void arrayFunction(int array[4]);

int main(void){
    int foo[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    printf("This is the address to foo in main:     \t%p\n",&foo[0]);
    arrayFunction(foo);
}

void arrayFunction(int array[4]){
    printf("This is the address to array in method: \t%p\n", &array[0]);
    array[0] = 22;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The is the address of `foo` aka `&foo[0]` is conceptually copied to a new variable.  Or said differently the pointer is still passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between the array and the normal element. If arr[10] is declared, then only (arr) gives the address of the first emement.
In your code, you have print address of the pointer pointing to that first element '&arr'. Just remove the '&' and both will show the same address.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void arrayFunction(int array[4]);

int main(void){
    int foo[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    printf("This is the address to foo in main: %p\n",foo);
    arrayFunction(foo);
}

void arrayFunction(int array[4]){
    printf("This is the address to array in method: %p\n",array);
    array[0] = 22;
}
```

[image: This is the output]